# Can Skype be made to beep differently for different people?

Tags: skype

Like the modern beep for messages from personal contacts and the oldschool beep for work contacts.

I am using Windows 8.1 and Skype Version 7.29.80.102

I have read that I could run Skype twice with two profiles, but then I'd have to either add the people from the different group again and remove them from my main profile just to get a different beep on IMs or find a way to forward IMs to the second profile for just the specific group of people.

Comment: Can you clarify the OS and Skype version you are using?

Comment: @Burgi just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible in the desktop version of Skype. You can do it in the Android version, but not the desktop version.

The feature has been requested on the Skype forums since [2014](https://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client-Ideas/Ability-to-set-different-sounds-for-different-people-coming-and/idi-p/2937573/page/1).

> Submitted by Queenmab on ‎22-02-2014 00:12
> Status: Under consideration
>
> I have many contacts and would like to be notified only when certain people come online or go offline.  But, Skype currently only allows for an "all or nothing" notification, so I am frequently notified about people that I really don't care about!

A Skype member of staff marked the idea as "Under Consideration" in March 2014 but there has been no obvious movement on this since. We can probably conclude that this feature is unlikely to be added in the near future.